# Django - Rest Framework Multiple models

Tags: python, django, json, rest, frameworks

I'm starting to use Django Rest Framework, it's a great tool!

I'm actually stuck in something easy, but no way to figure out how to do... I have two models, CustomUser and Order. Here, a CustomUser has 0 to many Orders.

I would like to generate a JSON HTTPResponse with the following format:

```
{
"user": {
    "city": "XXX", 
    "firstName": "XXX", 
    "zip": "XXX", 
    "taxNumber": "XXX", 
    "lastName": "XXX", 
    "street": "XXX", 
    "country": "XXX", 
    "email": "XXX"}, 
"orders": [{
        "id": "XXX",
        "plan": "XXX",
        "date": "XXX",
        "price": "XXX"
    }]
}
```

I already have my user in session (request) and I fetch the required Orders with the following line:

```
# 2. Load user's orders
orders = Order.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```

I've created two serializers "OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer)" and "CustomUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer)", but I've no clue how to merge both into the expected result.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Best regards

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The question is old, so it may have been answered, but something like this should work:

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer)
    class Meta:
        model = Order

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer)
    orders = OrderSerializer(many = True)
    class Meta:
        model = user
        fields = ('city', 'firstName', 'zip', 'taxNumber', 'lastName', 'street', 'country', 'email', 'orders')
```

Thanks,

SS

Comment: Still, how to use this serializer?  
`userializer = UserSerializer( Order.objects.get(pk=1), User.objects.filter(is_active=True) )
print userializer.data`.  Is this going to work?

Comment: Tried such a thing in my project. But I am not aware how to write the views.py for such a response. Can you please post the answer for this?

Answer (score 2):

Since `orders` are related to `user`, you should use [Nested relationships](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations.html#nested-relationships).

Comment: The link is broken

Comment: It seems to have been a link to DRF v2 http://www.tomchristie.com/rest-framework-2-docs/api-guide/relations.html#nested-relationships